# How to Clear Pending Changes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have some table data in the `DbContext` that I don't want to save. I have removed the database, set it up again, but the pending changes wont go away from the `DbContext`.

My database table is empty after rebuilding the database, but when I call the entity as a list of objects it still contains old objects. Is there any advice on how to clear the old pending data from the `DbContext` using Entity Framework 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are holding modified objects in the `DbContext`, right?

If that is so, then the problem is in the fact that you are reusing the same `DbContext` object in the subsequent operation. You should dispose of the `DbContext` as soon as your current operation is over, and then create the new one for the new operation.

Generally, all your operations should have this form:

```
using (DbContext context = new DbContext()) // Use concrete context type
{
    // Do stuff with context
    context.SaveChanges();
} // At this point your context seizes to exist
```

If anything goes wrong, like having an exception, or deciding not to call `SaveChanges`, all intermediate changes currently held in the context will be destroyed as well.

Comment: aha didn't think of that. But will the holding items get removed or how can I remove them?

Comment: You don't remove them. Just create new instance of your `DbContext` and it will be empty. It is general rule not to reuse `DbContexts` between operations. They cost memory and may even cause incorrect execution - which in fact happened in your example.

Comment: Okey now i'm understand it. Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't the real problem though i found out I had a hidden database that was in use and I had different connection strings when moving from my EF data access from mvc client to wcf service. But this is anyway a good answer!

Answer (score 3):

You have to dispose the DbContext

```
using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    // Do your thing...
    // Call ctx.SaveChanges();
}

using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    // Do your thing...
    // You should not find the data anymore
}
```