# Remove Pending Inserts in Entity Framework after failed savechanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am doing a batch insert of about 50 or so records.  It adds all the records and trys to save them all at once.

```
foreach(var item in MyItemsToSave)
{
   context.MyItems.Add(item);
}
context.SaveChantes();
```

If this fails I want to add them one by one.  I have some other logic to handle failures but I don't want to lose 49 valid records because one failed. I tried the following code:

```
foreach(var item in MyItemsToSave)
{
    context.MyItems.Add(item);
    try{
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      .......do something
    }
}
```

These two pieces of code both run in the same process.  The first section runs as best case scenario and then the second runs if the first portion of code fails.  What I determined is that the items in the batch portion of the code is still waiting to be inserted.  So when I call the savechanges method it is still trying to save the bad record.

How can I remove the records that failed (or all of them and start over)?

EDIT NOTE: 
Even with the second go around it will still fail because as soon as bad record gets in to the list it will try to insert it when your try the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Clear Pending Changes in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081178/how-to-clear-pending-changes-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @JohnM.Wright The solution to recreate the dbContext for each insert seems like overkill.  I am hoping for a better solution.

Comment: I had to use the recreate dbContext to make this work for now.  If I can figure out the steps needed to remove the enitity and retry I will update.  I do a lot of complicated inserts and I would like to be able to "batch" them in one connection and call.

Answer (score 0):

Better you save the changes one by one.

```
foreach(var item in MyItemsToSave)
{

    try{
        context.MyItems.Add(item);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       while (item.<FKColl>.Count > 0)
       {
           context.Detach(item.<FKColl>.First());
       }
      context.Detach(item);
    }
}
```

If any failed, Use `Detach` to remove the item from context(NOT IN DATASOURCE). Also you should remove the fk items before detaching the `item`

Comment: That doesn't work.  It keeps the bad record in memory.  I tried to remove it with context.MyItem.Remove(item) but that causes another issue on the next loop through with a foreign key error.